# Hats for characters

Tags: modeling, rigging, objects

I have a character with a hat and separate shoes. Should I be joining all separate objects when i'm about to rig a character?
**Edit:**
What are the benefits of each method, joining the parts in own object vs Keeping them separate.

Comment: I'd be inclined to parent them to your character. That way you could still have the wind blow his hat off without having to separate it from the body mesh! Select the character, then SHFT select the hat and CTRL-P > Object (Keep transform). You can then move the character around and the hat will follow it but you can still move the hat separately.

Comment: ah nice, should i do the same to the shoes?

Comment: That answer would really have to be be opinion-based. Personally I'd probably have modelled them as part of the legs, but it depends whether you want to take them off or not! You could of course parent the hat to the head bone of the armature rather than directly to the head, but I'm not sure what would be best for the shoes.